# WordPress loop alternate rows and columns each two posts with bootstrap

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create a loop for wordpress that returns each two posts inside its own div and alternating columns every new row (see example)... Im not experimented in php enough to make this happen.  I dont manage to get it working appropiatly. And see how to make the last div to bee 100% width if it does not have another column.

I would appreciate your support to make this happen since I tried many things and still no luck. (im using visual composer bootstrap classes, it does work but not as expected.This is the example I want to create

[image]

This is my code:

```
 <?php 
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'post_type'     => 'inversion',
    'category_name' => '',
    'order'         => 'DESC',
    'orderby'       => 'DATE'
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :  ?>
<div class="vc_row">
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();  $i++; $imagen = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full');  ?>



  <?php if(($i % 2) == 2) :  ?>

            <div class="vc_col-sm-6">


                            <div class="vc_row vc_row-fluid">
                                 <div class="vc_col-sm-6 cont-izq">
                                     <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3> 
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="vc_col-sm-6 cont-der" >
                                    <a class="click-info">Más Información</a>
                                        <div class="img-dentro kenburns-top" style="background:url(<?php echo $imagen; ?>)no-repeat; background-size:cover;">

                                        </div>
                                 </div>

                         </div>
                        </div>   


<?php else : ?>

                             <div class="vc_col-sm-6">


                            <div class="vc_row vc_row-fluid">

                                 <div class="vc_col-sm-6 cont-der" >
                                    <a class="click-info">Más Información</a>
                                        <div class="img-dentro kenburns-top" style="background:url(<?php echo $imagen; ?>)no-repeat; background-size:cover;">

                                        </div>
                                 </div>
                                  <div class="vc_col-sm-6 cont-izq">
                                     <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3> 
                                 </div>

                         </div>
                        </div>   

<?php endif; endwhile;  ?>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query();  ?>
```

Comment: `$i % 2 == 2` would be false, **always**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDIT]Try this:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'post_type'      => 'inversion',
    'category_name'  => '',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'orderby'        => 'date',
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :  ?>
    <div class="vc_row">
        <?php
            $float_class = '';
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
                $the_query->the_post();

                if ( $the_query->current_post &&
                $the_query->current_post % 2 === 0 ) {
                    $float_class = $float_class ? '' : 'vc_pull-right';
                }

                $imagen = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_the_ID(), 'full' );
        ?>
            <div class="vc_col-sm-6">
                <div class="vc_row vc_row-fluid">
                    <div class="vc_col-sm-6 cont-der <?php echo $float_class; ?>">
                        <a class="click-info">Más Información</a>
                        <div class="img-dentro kenburns-top" style="background:url('<?php echo esc_url( $imagen ); ?>') no-repeat; background-size:cover;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="vc_col-sm-6 cont-izq">
                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; // end have_posts() loop ?>
    </div><!-- .vc_row -->
<?php endif; // end have_posts() check ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem maybe I have everything wrong haha this makes the first row different as the second.  Im trying to make the first two posts of the first row to have the same design and then the second row with the other two posts to alternate the design.  Have any idea?